# Integrating Homegraph api to my smarthome

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I am currently creating a smarthome automation. I am using Laravel PHP in my cloud. I am done with Oauth2 Authentication and sending commands from Google Home App to my devices (I used MQTT to communicate with my devices).

I have already implemented successfully `SYNC`, `QUERY` and `EXECUTE`. and now i want to synchronize the rooms and structures for which i have to use the Homegraph API. Is there somebody who can guide me in intergrating the Homegraph APi to my Smarthome because i am facing problem here in JWT authentication? My app is based on laravel so i am not able to follow the sample codes. I tried like this:

```
$jsonFile = json_decode(file_get_contents('./key.json'), true);
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $payload = [
        "iss" => $jsonFile['client_email'],
        "scope" => "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/homegraph",
        "aud" => "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
        "iat" => date("h:i:sa"),
        "exp" => date("h:i:sa", strtotime('+1 hour'))
    ];
    $jwt = JWT::encode($payload, $jsonFile["private_key"], 'RS256');
    $header =  array("Authorization" => "Bearer " .  $jwt, "Content-Type" => "application/json");
    try {$response = $client->get( "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", [
        "headers" => $header]);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        dd($e);
    }
```

I am getting an error of

```
    Client error: `GET https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, w (truncated...)
```

i am following this http post [link](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/request-sync)

Comment: I'd suggest using a JWT library to simplify your integration. Additionally, it looks like you're sending a `GET` request but you probably want to use a `POST`.

Comment: I tried using `POST` request and i got this error ``Client error: `POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
    {
      "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
      "error_description": "Invalid grant_type: "
    }`` I am using the firebase/php-jwt library.

Comment: @NickFelker do you have any idea how can i resolved this? i followed the steps on [Homegraph Documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/request-sync) and i still cannot get access tokens.

Comment: I'd suggest checking out the [google-auth PHP library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-php)

Answer (score 2):

Using [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client), should allow you to integrate directly w/ the Homegraph API from a PHP based Smart Home fulfilment without having to handcraft HTTP request and authorization.

It can leverages [Google Application Default credentials](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client#authentication-with-service-accounts) to authorize the application using a service account key:

```
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/key.json');

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/homegraph");
```

It includes [generated bindings](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services/tree/master/src/Google/Service/HomeGraphService.php) for the Homegraph API:

```
$homegraphService = new Google_Service_HomeGraphService($client);
$homegraphService->devices->reportStateAndNotification(...);
```

And [generated types](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services/tree/master/src/Google/Service/HomeGraphService) for all Homegraph API request and response payload, for example implementing [Report State](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/report-state) would look like this:

```
$request = new Google_Service_HomeGraphService_ReportStateAndNotificationRequest();
$request->setAgentUserId("placeholder-user-id");
$request->setRequestId("placeholder-request-id");
$payload = new Google_Service_HomeGraphService_StateAndNotificationPayload();
$devices = new Google_Service_HomeGraphService_ReportStateAndNotificationDevice();
$devices->setStates(array(
    "placeholder-device-id" => array(
        "placeholder-state-key" => ...
    )
));
$payload->setDevices($devices);
$request->setPayload($payload);
$homegraphService->devices->reportStateAndNotification($request));
```